# Invalid JSON 'claims' value encountered

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL for Android and confused about this error:

```
com.microsoft.identity.common.java.exception.ServiceException: Invalid JSON 'claims' value encountered
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.ExceptionAdapter.exceptionFromAcquireTokenResult(ExceptionAdapter.java:96)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher.getCommandResultFromTokenResult(CommandDispatcher.java:572)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher.executeCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:480)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher.access$100(CommandDispatcher.java:85)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher$5.run(CommandDispatcher.java:648)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
 Caused by: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalServiceException: Invalid JSON 'claims' value encountered
    at com.microsoft.identity.client.internal.controllers.MsalExceptionAdapter.msalExceptionFromBaseException(MsalExceptionAdapter.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.identity.client.SingleAccountPublicClientApplication$3.onError(SingleAccountPublicClientApplication.java:351)
    at com.microsoft.identity.client.SingleAccountPublicClientApplication$3.onError(SingleAccountPublicClientApplication.java:337)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher.commandCallbackOnError(CommandDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher.access$1000(CommandDispatcher.java:85)
    at com.microsoft.identity.common.java.controllers.CommandDispatcher$4.run(CommandDispatcher.java:514)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

how to fix this com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalServiceException?

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the issue? Currently, encountering it now. Also encountered it 2 days ago but worked fine yesterday. So I'm still looking for the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an expired Azure Subscription. The free trial has ended and I had to upgrade to pay as you go subscription.

Go to Cost Management in Azure Portal and check for red boxes or warnings and fix them.

Answer (score -1):

I detected today the same issue, without any change on the code, I get now the error message. The LogIn screen is shown, I can indicate user and password, but then I get the same exception.
I renewed already the app registration in Azure, but no solution.
Did you change anything in your app before? Or did you add any new library?

Comment: This is not really an answer, is it?

Comment: Not really an answer, is it?